# What is the proper term for this hose line from the fuel tank?

Tags: jaguar

I have a 1991 Jaguar XJ6 4.0, and my question is what is the name of this line coming from the fuel tank. There's 2 lines and they're stripped, and I can't seem to find them anywhere.

This is the tank where the two lines run: 
[image]

This is the line:
[image]

the problem is, I don't know the name of this line, and when I type in fuel lines, and other terms for this line, i get something completely opposite of what it is in this image.

and ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What's at the other end? What do they connect to?

Comment: On [this website](http://www.jaguarclassicparts.com/uk/jaguar-xj6-parts/air-and-fuel-delivery-systems/fuel-pipes-and-hoses/fuel-pipes-2-9-4-0-litre) they are calling them "fuel pipes", but I still don't know it's exactly what you are looking for. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Those are quick couplers for the fuel lines.. A bugger to find second hand as most people wreck them taking them off but you can buy them new from Jaguar Heritage/Classic parts in the UK.

Comment: Do you have a part number or some such which will make finding the part easier?

Comment: http://www.jaguarclassicparts.com/uk